# Ignore pylint no-member errors for the module psycopg2.errors using pyproject.toml

Tags: python, psycopg2, pylint

How can I ignore the pylint error:

```
E1101: Module 'psycopg2.errors' has no 'RaiseException' member (no-member)
```

by a setting in the `pyproject.toml`. Looking in `pylint --help` there seems to be `ignored-modules` under the `Main` section, so I've tried adding:

```
[tool.pylint."MAIN"]
ignored-modules = ["psycopg2.errors"]
```

To the file - but it's not suppressed / ignored the warnings related to the module, i feel as though i'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (with `alembic`) this worked:

```ini
[tool.pylint]
ignored-modules = ["alembic.context"]
```

This even fixed issues with internal submodules, for exmaple:

```py
from alembic import context
config = context.config  # Would raise no-member
```

So for your case, I suppose this should work:

```ini
[tool.pylint]
ignored-modules = ["psycopg2.errors"]
```

If you are using vscode, close the file and open it again so `pylint` tiggers again. If you want all `psycopg2` lints use `psycopg2`.